# Visualizing a three way interaction between 2 categorical variables and one continuous ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, interaction

I would like to plot pupil size (continuous) over time (continuous) as a function of Variable A (2 levels) and Variable B (3 levels). I would like to use different colors for A and line type for B. An example of what I would like to do is displayed is Figure 2A in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-47961-4):

[image]

I tried to follow the suggestion of eipi in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086652/visualising-a-three-way-interaction-between-two-continuous-variables-and-one-cat/62817319#62817319) but it does not work for me (below):
this is the code

```
ggplot(
  make_pred_dat(nB=3),  
  aes(x=IVContinuousA, y=DV, colour=IVCategorical, linetype=factor(round(IVContinuousB,2)))
) +  
  geom_line()
```

Could you give me some feedback?

Comment: Please can you include some data so your problem is reproducible with `dput(make_pred_dat(nB = 3))`

Comment: I added Figure 4 from the link you gave, although it doesn't seem to match your description exactly??  What does "does not work" mean: do you get errors or warnings?  Do you get a plot but not what you want?  Can you provide a link to the figure that you made and explain what's wrong about it?